# Calculate total of all dynamic items upon submit of form including copied items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to calculate the total of a list of dynamic form option items, example :

product name
product description
quantity
price
total

I have a script that automatically adds item rows :

```
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[Invoice][itemNo][]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[Invoice][itemName][]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Invoice][price][]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Invoice][quantity][]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Invoice][total][]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox" name="data[Invoice][staged][]" id="itemStaged_'+i+'"></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});
```

and the script that does the totalling :

```
$(document).on('change keyup blur','#tax',function(){
    calculateTotal();
});

//total price calculation 
function calculateTotal(){
    subTotal = 0 ; total = 0; 
    $('.totalLinePrice').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '' )subTotal += parseFloat( $(this).val() );
    });
    $('#subTotal').val( subTotal.toFixed(2) );
    tax = $('#tax').val();
    if(tax != '' && typeof(tax) != "undefined" ){
        taxAmount = subTotal * ( parseFloat(tax) /100 );
        $('#taxAmount').val(taxAmount.toFixed(2));
        total = subTotal + taxAmount;
    }else{
        $('#taxAmount').val(0);
        total = subTotal;
    }
    $('#totalAftertax').val( total.toFixed(2) );
    calculateAmountDue();
}
```

So what happens now, you tab or press enter to cycle through the fields, and after you update the qty and tab through, it updates the total for that item, as well as the overall total.

The PROBLEM is that if you COPY and PASTE form fields using the following script :

```
//copies the selected table rows to new ones
$(".copy").on('click', function() {
    var origs=$('.case:checkbox:checked');
    for(var a=0; a<origs.length; a++) {
        addNewRow();
        var arr = origs.closest('tr')[a].id.split('_');
        var id = arr[arr.length-1];
        var dat = getValues(id);
        setValues(i-1, dat);
    }
    $('#check_all').add(origs).prop("checked", false);
    // Tried adding calculateTotal(); in this line to no avail...
});
```

The copied rows are not updated on the overall total.  This is driving me insane, does anyone have a solution or tutorial on how to do this?

Requests : (show addNewRow function)

```
var addNewRow = function(id){
    html = '<tr id="tr_'+i+'">';
    html += '<input type="hidden" id="stock_'+i+'"/>';
    html += '<input type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_'+i+'" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][stockMaintainer]" />';
    html += '<input type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_'+i+'"/>';
    html += '<input type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_'+i+'"/>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" id="caseNo_'+i+'" type="checkbox" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);"/></td>';
    html += '<td class="prod_c"><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][product_id]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);">';
    html +='<span class="add_icon" id="add_icon_'+i+'"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>';
    html +='<span class="subtract_icon" id="subtract_icon_'+i+'"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>';
    html +='</td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][productName]"  id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][price]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][quantity]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">';
    html += '</td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice addNewRow" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][staged]" id="staged_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][added]" id="added_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><select name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][location]" id="location_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">';
    html += '<option value="Used">Used</option>';
    html += '<option value="RTS">RTS</option>';
    html += '<option value="LAJ">LAJ</option>';
    html += '</select></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
        $('#tr_'+id).after(html);
    }else{
        $('table').append(html);
    }
    $('#caseNo_'+i).focus();
    i++;
}
```

(getValues) Code :

```
var getValues=function(id){
        var inputs=$('#tr_'+id).find('select,input,textarea').filter('[name]');
        var values={};
        for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++){
            var cur=inputs[i];
            values[cur.name.match(/\[\w+]$/)||cur.name] = $(cur).is(':checkbox, :radio') ? cur.checked : cur.value;
        }
        return values;
    };
```

(setValues) :

```
var setValues=function(id,values){
        var inputs=$('#tr_'+id);
        for(var i in values){
            var cur=inputs.find('[name$="'+i+'"]');
            if(cur.is(':checkbox, :radio')) {
                cur.prop('checked', values[i]);
            } else {
                cur.val(values[i]);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: it will be really helpfull if you can share your code in plunker or jsbin.

Comment: Is the "total" calculated correctly after you copied some rows and then modifiy different single row again? Or are the copied rows always ignored? Also the i variable in your addNewRow is not defined. Don't you get any warnings/errors in your console?

Comment: @Torge oddly enough the copied rows are always ignored.  I think this is because it is a "dumb" function that does the calculating, as far as I can see, it looks for your cursor to go from the "price" field, to the "qty" field, then autocalculates it row by row.  I want it to basically either have the ability to recalculate upon the addition of copied items, OR just do the calculation AFTER the user is done adding items(upon submitting the form)

Comment: Put an `alert($(this).attr("id")+": "+$(this).val())` (or log to console) directly after this line `$('.totalLinePrice').each(function(){` and see if it also alerts the content of the copied row. If not I assume the content is not correctly set in the new rows. If it is alerted it must be a problem of the calculateTotal() function.

Comment: @Torge Thats a cool tidbit of code... what it does is this : every time I copy a line, it says "total_1/x" as in x= how many times I copied.  It does not reuse existing x, so if I started with lines 1,2,3,4, and copied 3 lines, the output would be "total_1,total_2,total_3,total_4,total_5,total_6,total_7"  this is correct even when doing multiple copies

Comment: Ok it does not ignore the lines then. But no values, just the IDs? What fields are populated with actual numbers? Most browser have the ability to set a breakpoint in the javascript code, so it stops execution there and you can continue step by step and see what happens. (Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint) I suggest you set soem break points inside the calcuateTotal and try to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Please include code for `getValues` and `setValues`. I replicated your code in simpler form and did not have any problems when I called `calculateTotal()` at the end of the copy function. There may be an exception thrown from `getValues` or `setValues` that prevents the call to `calculateTotal` from firing. Please check your console and debugger as suggested by others; also, you have a LOT of stuff going on here - recommend start with simplest possible case, get the mechanism working, then expand.

Comment: Also - if you are POSTing form to the server you want to set the `name` attributes, not the `id` attributes (`name` is for HTTP POST form data; `id` is for programmatic control). If you are using AJAX, on the other hand, then what you are doing by setting each individual control's ID is wasteful - instead simply set the ID at the row level (the `TR`, for example via a `data` attribute), and then descend from there to compute the per-row values when submitting to the server.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary I am new to javascript/jquery - how would I debug js/jquery to get those gets/sets?

Comment: These days the browser usually includes a Debugger or Developer Tools; F12 key opens this for Firefox/Chrome/IE on Windows OS. Check the `Console` tab for errors. In Chrome you can click on the error to jump to offending source code, which is handy. If you create a Fiddle or post the code for those missing methods I could take a closer look.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Thanks for the info on that, I was using Tools-Web Developer-Toggle Tools-Network to debug, that helps a lot as well.  I updated my question with the info you requested

Comment: Found the bug - was missing the `name` attribute on the total column that got copied. Pretty simple fix to add the attribute and call `calculateTotal` please see answer with working code below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addNewRow` function is not setting a `name` attribute on the `total` textbox.

However, your `getValues` and `setValues` functions are using the `[name]` attribute selector to get and set values in the cloned rows. Because `addNewRow` did not set the `name` attribute, the total value fails to populate in the cloned row, and therefore the total does not change because `calculateTotal` interprets this value as `0`.

Problem code is here:

```
  html += '<td><input type="text" id="total_' + i + '" class="form-control totalLinePrice addNewRow" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
```

Here is the fixed line of code: (and also remember to call `calculateTotal` in your `copy` handler)

```
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][total]" id="total_' + i + '" class="form-control totalLinePrice addNewRow" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
```

See working (but slightly simplified) snippet below: ([or see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wgqvndq/))

```js
$(document).on('change keyup blur', '#tax', function() {
  calculateTotal();
});
IsNumeric = tabE = function() {
  return true
}
var i = 0;

var addNewRow = function(id) {
  var html = '<tr id="tr_' + i + '">';
  html += '<input type="hidden" id="stock_' + i + '"/>';
  html += '<input type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_' + i + '" name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][stockMaintainer]" />';
  html += '<input type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_' + i + '"/>';
  html += '<input type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_' + i + '"/>';
  html += '<td><input class="case" id="caseNo_' + i + '" type="checkbox" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);"/></td>';
  html += '<td class="prod_c"><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][product_id]" id="itemNo_' + i + '" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);">';
  html += '<span class="add_icon" id="add_icon_' + i + '"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>';
  html += '<span class="subtract_icon" id="subtract_icon_' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][productName]"  id="itemName_' + i + '" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][price]" id="price_' + i + '" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][quantity]" id="quantity_' + i + '" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][total]" id="total_' + i + '" class="form-control totalLinePrice addNewRow" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][staged]" id="staged_1' + i + '" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][added]" id="added_1' + i + '" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="data[InvoiceDetail][' + i + '][location]" id="location_1' + i + '" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">';
  html += '<option value="Used">Used</option>';
  html += '<option value="RTS">RTS</option>';
  html += '<option value="LAJ">LAJ</option>';
  html += '</select></td>';
  html += '</tr>';

  if (typeof id !== "undefined") {
    $('#tr_' + id).after(html);
  } else {
    $('table').append(html);
  }
  $('#caseNo_' + i).focus();
  i++;
}

$(".addmore").on('click', function() {
  html = '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[Invoice][itemNo][]" id="itemNo_' + i + '" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[Invoice][itemName][]" id="itemName_' + i + '" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Invoice][price][]" id="price_' + i + '" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Invoice][quantity][]" id="quantity_' + i + '" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Invoice][total][]" id="total_' + i + '" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
  html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox" name="data[Invoice][staged][]" id="itemStaged_' + i + '"></td>';
  html += '</tr>';
  $('table').append(html);
  i++;
});

//copies the selected table rows to new ones
$(".copy").on('click', function() {
  var origs = $('.case:checkbox:checked');
  for (var a = 0; a < origs.length; a++) {
    addNewRow();
    var arr = origs.closest('tr')[a].id.split('_');
    var id = arr[arr.length - 1];
    var dat = getValues(id);
    setValues(i - 1, dat);
  }
  $('#check_all').add(origs).prop("checked", false);
  calculateTotal();
});

//total price calculation 
function calculateTotal() {
  subTotal = 0;
  total = 0;
  $('.totalLinePrice').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') subTotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  $('#subTotal').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
  tax = $('#tax').val();
  if (tax != '' && typeof(tax) != "undefined") {
    taxAmount = subTotal * (parseFloat(tax) / 100);
    $('#taxAmount').val(taxAmount.toFixed(2));
    total = subTotal + taxAmount;
  } else {
    $('#taxAmount').val(0);
    total = subTotal;
  }
  $('#totalAftertax').val(total.toFixed(2));
  //calculateAmountDue();
}

var getValues = function(id) {
  var inputs = $('#tr_' + id).find('select,input,textarea').filter('[name]');
  var values = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var cur = inputs[i];
    values[cur.name.match(/\[\w+]$/) || cur.name] = $(cur).is(':checkbox, :radio') ? cur.checked : cur.value;
  }
  return values;
};

var setValues = function(id, values) {
  var inputs = $('#tr_' + id);
  for (var i in values) {
    var cur = inputs.find('[name$="' + i + '"]');
    if (cur.is(':checkbox, :radio')) {
      cur.prop('checked', values[i]);
    } else {
      cur.val(values[i]);
    }
  }
};

addNewRow()
addNewRow()
```

```css
input {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Tax rate
  <input type="text" id="tax" value="8.7">
</div>
<div>
  Tax amt
  <input type="text" id="taxAmount" value="0">
</div>
<div>
  Total
  <input type="text" id="totalAftertax" value="0">
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" class="copy">COPY CHECKED ROWS (check some rows first)</a>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>copy</th>
      <th>product code</th>
      <th>product name</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>qty</th>
      <th>total</th>
      <th>staged</th>
      <th>added</th>
      <th>location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: forgot to mention - I commented out `calculateAmountDue()` because you didn't post that function.. if you copy my code be sure to uncomment that line, of course!

Comment: Thank you very much!  That was exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling  `calculateTotal();` function on `change` `keyup` and `blur`
events.this works as long as you interact with form elements.

but when you copy the row.you wont be interacting with textboxes.so those change,blur and keyup events wont get fired and as a result `calculateTotal()`
will not be executed.as a result you cant see any update on total value.

to overcome this you have to call `calculateTotal()` in copy function.

Comment: please assume you are talking to a complete newb in javascript/jquery(slowly painfully trying to teach myself, delving into code by others to help), how would I create a "copy event listener"? I added "calculateTotal();" to the function of my copy code, but that did not work(see question)

Comment: not a copy event listener.its copy element's click event listener.

Comment: Basically to the end of my click event function that copies the data?  Please see my answer, I tried doing that

Comment: sure, one moment please - added

Comment: @PavanTeja In that case I would recommend you to try to set up a simplified version of your problem in JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/). Most likely you will already find the answer yourself in the process. But if not, you can post the JSFiddle result together with your question and we can easily give you a fixed JSFiddle version.